# Counting and aggregating data based on five minutes time interval

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse, aggregation

My data `df` looks like this

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4)
Time <- c("7:44:29","7:44:30","7:45:31","7:46:35","7:47:37","7:48:34","7:49:35","7:50:36",'7:51:13',"7:52:14","7:52:15","7:53:16")
Speed_kmh <- c(2,5,8,2,4,6,9,8,6,8,10,14)
Distance_m <- c(162,162,162,162,162,162,162,157,150,137,122,102)
df <- data.frame(ID, Time, Speed_kmh, Distance_m)
df
          ID    Time Speed_kmh Distance_m
   1      1 7:44:29         2        162
   2      1 7:44:30         5        162
   3      1 7:45:31         8        162
   4      2 7:46:35         2        162
   5      2 7:47:37         4        162
   6      2 7:48:34         6        162
   7      3 7:49:35         9        162
   8      3 7:50:36         8        157
   9      3 7:51:13         6        150
   10     3 7:52:14         8        137
   11     4 7:52:15        10        122
   12     4 7:53:16        14        102
```

I want to do two things based on five minutes interval

1- Count the number of unique ID values

2- Average the Speed_kmh and Distance_m values

The desired output should look like this.

```
  ID    Time Speed_kmh Distance_m
1  2 7:48:34         5        162
2  2 7:53:16         9        138
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

```
library(lubridate)
lilibrary(data.table)

df1 %>%
  mutate(Time = hms(Time)) %>%
  mutate(tt = floor(lubridate::minute(Time - Time[1])/5) ) %>%
  group_by(tt) %>%
  summarize(ID = length(unique(ID)), Time = last(Time), Speed_kmh = mean(Speed_kmh), Distance_m = mean(Distance_m)) %>%
  select(-tt)


     ID Time       Speed_kmh Distance_m
  <dbl> <Period>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1     2 7H 48M 34S      4.5        162 
2     2 7H 53M 16S      9.17       138.

df1 %>%
  mutate(Time = hms(Time)) %>%
  mutate(ttt= (lubridate::minute(Time) + lubridate::hour(Time)* 60)) %>%
  mutate(tt = floor(ttt/5) ) %>%
  group_by(tt) %>%
  summarize(ID = length(unique(ID)), Time = last(Time), Speed_kmh = mean(Speed_kmh), Distance_m = mean(Distance_m))

     tt    ID Time       Speed_kmh Distance_m
  <dbl> <int> <Period>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1    92     1 7H 44M 30S       3.5       162 
2    93     3 7H 49M 35S       5.8       162 
3    94     2 7H 53M 16S       9.2       134.
```

Comment: I want to count a number of unique IDs that occur in the 5 minutes interval and not just the last ID value. Actually, the ID column represents the number of vehicles, I want to count how many vehicles occur in 5 minutes and what is their average speed and distance.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @SorathAbbasi I edit my code. Please check it out.

Comment: This works perfectly for this sample data. However, when I apply this code to actual data it gives me output with 12 rows for 24 hours (60/5). Is it possible to do this 5 minutes interval estimation separately for each hour? So that the final output contains 288 rows?

Comment: @SorathAbbasi I add the code. I didn't remove `tt` this time. You may change that's name yourself.

Comment: It solved my issue, Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible to classify these estimations based on date as well? For example, I have 5 days of data and I want to see the 5 minutes interval estimation separately for Day, Hour, and Minute.